# Find $P(k \notin A+A)$ on a series of Bernoulli trials $A$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

We given set $\{0, 1, \dots n-1\}$.
Then we conduct series of Bernoulli trials with success chance $p= \frac 1 2$.
If at the $i$-th trial yields success, then we add $i$ to the set $A$.
So, by the end of the experiment we end up $A \subseteq \{0, 1, \dots n-1\}$.

Now, define a sum operation for these sets. $A+B = \{a+b : a \in A, b\in B\}$.
Task is to find this probability: $P(k \notin A+A)$ for $k = 0,1, \dots 2n$

**Note** Solution must have no summation symbol but it's allowed to consider different cases.

**My solution**
Let's consider an example.
$n = 5$ and $A = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$.
Now:
For $k = 0$ there is 1 way to represent it as sum of two numbers from $A$: $(0,0)$ P(0) = $\frac 1 2$
For $k = 1$ There are 1 way: $(0,1)$
For $k = 2$ There are 2 ways: $(0,2) (1,1)$
For $k = 3$ There are 2 ways: $(0,3) (1,2)$
For $k = 4$ There are 3 ways: $(0,4)(1,3)(2,2)$
After that I was able to grasp that odd number $k$ have $\lfloor \frac k 2 \rfloor + 1$ possible representations, and even number have $\frac k 2 $ representations and plus one trivial (0.5k + 0.5k).
This helped me to derive generic formula:
$$
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
    {\frac 3 4}^{\lfloor \frac k 2 \rfloor + 1}, & k \equiv 1 (\mod 2)\\
    \frac 1 2 {\frac 3 4}^{\frac k 2}, & k \equiv 0 (\mod 2)
\end{cases}$$
But I'm worried about special cases. for example, I believe $P(2n) = P(2n-1)= 0$

I would appreciate If you guys would take a look and checked if this is correct.
Many thanks!